# Amazon s3: How can I name a new folder after each new username?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-s3, social-networking

I'm creating a simple Instagram-type social media app specifically for sharing images using javascript and node.js. I'm storing the new user information (name, username, password) in a MySQL database and I'm saving the images in an S3 bucket.

I would like to create a new folder for each new user and name the folder after the username. Does anyone have any tips on how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Tips on how to do it? Use the Amazon Javascript SDK to create a bucket and upload images to it. Here's an example from their website: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html . If you have some code you have tried we could maybe help you with more specific questions.

Comment: Also, depending on how your user names are created, be aware of the recommendations for the [characters to use for the object key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) (scroll down just a bit to "Characters That Might Require Special Handling" and "Characters to Avoid").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. Rather, the name ('Key') of each object includes the *full path* of the object.

For example, `image.png` in the `john/` folder is actually just an object called `john/image.png`.

Thus, the **folders are automatically created** whenever an object is stored in that path. The folders also automatically disappear when there are no objects left in a path (after an object is deleted).

Therefore, you simply need to store your image with the appropriate path and the 'folder' will automatically appear.

**Tip:** It might be a better idea to name the 'folders' with a **unique ID rather than a username**. This is because users might want to **change username** in future and this would not be possible if the objects are named with the username. Using a **unique id** instead would avoid this problem. (In the same way, you should use a unique ID in your database table rather than indexing and joining on Username.)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped clear up most of my problems with s3